# Get ancestor of xpath query

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I'm using IMPORTXML with Google sheets. I want to convert the following nested lists into a table. Technically the document is a table with lists in each cell.

[image]
*Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup*

Here's my ideal table layout:

```
| Name      | Section |
| ---       | ---     |
| Australia | AFC     |
| Iran      | AFC     |
| ...       | ...     |
```

I've used these two queries:
`//*[@id='mw-content-text']/div/div[9]/table/tr/td/ul/li/../../dl/dt/a`
and
`//*[@id='mw-content-text']/div/div[9]/table/tr/td/ul/li/span/a/ancestor::td/dl/dt/a`

The problem is, as you can guess and I can't figure out why, all those queries do is grab a list of `AFC, CAF, CONCACAF, CONMEBOL, OFC, UEFA` whereas I would like to simple grab the top level element from each of the matching sub elements.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First column: `=IMPORTXML("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup","//h3/span[text()=""Qualification""]/parent::h3/following-sibling::div[2]//li/span/a")`

Second column:
`=IMPORTXML("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup","//h3/span[text()=""Qualification""]/parent::h3/following-sibling::div[2]//li/span/a[text()="""&A1&"""]/ancestor::ul/preceding-sibling::dl")`

Note that the xpath in the second column refers to column A so if you don't start on the first row, you should update this reference

Comment: This is basically the solution I ended up coming up with too. There's not really a way to say, grab n items, and for each of n, go one level higher. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following selector:

```
//*[@id='mw-content-text']/div/div/table[@class='multicol']//li/parent::ul/preceding-sibling::dl/dt/a
```

Let me know if that works for you as it is giving me just those headings.